# pandas plot histogram of column with color indicating the fraction of counts belonging to a category based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, data-visualization

for simplicity lets say i have a dataframe with two columns 'annual income' and 'gender'

i want to plot a histogram of the annual income with each bin with a color indicating the fraction of male/female that are in that bin.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = {'annual_income':np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,)),'gender':np.random.randint(0,2,(1000,))}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.hist(column='annual_income')
```

so far i can just plot the histogram of annual income, but i want that each bin will be colored by the fraction of male/female that constitute the bin.
if there is a more classic way to visualize the same idea i would appreciate that too

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.  Does this work? `pd.crosstab(df.annual_income, df.gender).plot.bar(stacked=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.cut` or `value_counts` to bin, then `pd.crosstab` as suggested in the comment:

```
# pass your bins here, you can also pass an array
(pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['annual_income'], bins=5),
             df['gender'], normalize='index')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]